# Visa application asking if you have a residence in country other than your nationality

Tags: visas, france, student-visas

I have a valid student visa for Russia. I am applying for France, in the application form, it says, do you have a residence in a country other than your current nationality. Do I check No or Yes? Does student visa goes as residence for such question?

Original question: Résidence dans un pays autre que celui de la nationalité actuelle.

Non.
Oui. Titre de séjour ou équivalent: .................

Answer (score 4):

The visa by itself does not make you a resident in that country: you could have a visa and not use it.

The question is whether you are actually residing in a country different from your citizenship country. If you are studying there, unless it's a very short-term course (often less than 3 months, sometimes up to 6, depending on the country), you would usually be considered a resident there.

Note that for many people, this is actually a positive point: if a country has given you a long-term visa, that usually means they have checked your situation.

However, for some countries (France being one of them, IIRC), you are supposed to apply to the embassy/consulate that covers your place of residence, so if you are not there it makes things more complex.

If you are studying there and are at home for a short time for holidays, then you should probably wait until you are back in your country of residence before applying for the visa.

If you were studying there but have now finished your studies and are back in your home country, you should probably answer no.

As you see, the right answer depends a lot on the specifics, so the more details you provide, the more accurate answers will be.

Answer (score 3):

When you are uncertain in a case like this, it is always best to choose the option that leads to the disclosure of more information, so you should choose "yes."  It's not like an academic exam where you are penalized for giving the wrong answer no matter what.

If you choose "no" when you should have chosen "yes," you may be seen as withholding pertinent information, and, worse, you may be suspected of doing so willfully, possibly for malicious ends.

On the other hand, if you choose "yes" when you should have chosen "no," the official processing your application will just dismiss the extra information as superfluous.  You will likely give the impression of being forthcoming.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, a student visa is sufficient to establish that you are a resident and not a mere visitor. Usually, the local French consulate provides a list of the documents it accepts to prove you satisfy this requirement. Note that if you are not able to present any of these documents, you would usually be expected to apply for the visa in your country of origin.

Comment: I am applying from my home country.

Comment: Then you should refer to @phoog's answer.

Comment: @Papa Why are you applying in your country of origin? Are you planning to go back to Russia before your trip or do you prefer to avoid that?